# Matplotlibs subplots: actual number of subplots unknown in advance

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to add subplots in a loop only under a certain condition, so the number of subplots is unknown in advance (although I know the limit would be the number of iterations). I tried the following:

1. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(iterations_limit)` followed by `ax[i].remove()` to remove the extra axes, this works but there is a blank space in the figure for the axes that got removed
2. Create a new subplot after the number of subplots become known, and copy the axes objects from ax. It seems that axes copying doesn't quite work either

How can I either remove the extra axes while also removing their assigned space in the figure OR only add subplots that I need without knowning their count in advance?

Comment: I'd say neither, nor. Instead find out how many subplots you need in advance, then plot to those subplots.

Comment: By the time I know the number of suplots, I'd have already lost all complex computations (and other plot details) after the loop is done. To save those data frames and details or rerun them again is not optimal

Comment: That's a question of code design or optimization.

Comment: Cache all the data that would get plotted, then plot afterwards? Something like `plot_data = []; for i in lst: if condition: plot_data.append({'x': x_data, 'y': y_data, 'label': label_name});`?

Comment: That's possible but I prefer not going that route because that includes large dataframes, with all other associated details. I would do that as a last resort but the question is whether I can add subplots for a dynamic number of plots or adjust a figure geometry after the axes were added

Comment: You can. But you don't want to, because that's twice as complicated as just keeping track of the results to be plotted.

Comment: An alternative to these other (excellent) suggestions might be to make your plots one at a time, then compose them into a large figure afterwards, e.g. with `PIL` or [`svgwrite`](https://pypi.org/project/svgwrite/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'd assumed it should be an easy task but it looks like (also from other questions I came across) it is not. Since I eventually want to create an HTML report with figures, I will just go with multiple plots as suggested